# Filling contour levels with grain (texture) using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, r, contour, filling

I created a program to draw temperature contour map of France:

This is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gstat)
library(sp)
library(maptools)
require(rgeos)
library(rgdal) 
library(foreign)
library(maptools)
library(knitr)
library(jsonlite)
library(raster)
library(leaflet)

#récupérer les données a partir de json
dataJson <- fromJSON(readLines('jsonallcoor.js'))
# Téléchargement du fond de carte
FRA=readShapePoly("FRA_adm0.shp")

#concour (interpolation idw)
x=data.frame(0)
y=data.frame(0)
t=data.frame(0)
for ( i in 1:103) { 
  x[i]<- as.data.frame.factor(dataJson[[i]]$longitude)# define x & y as longitude and latitude
  y[i]<- as.data.frame.factor(dataJson[[i]]$latitude)
  t[i]<- as.data.frame.factor(dataJson[[i]]$temperature)
}
#changer le nom de dataframe 

x<- as.numeric(x) 
y <- as.numeric(y) 
temperature<- as.numeric(t)
frame=as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,temperature))
frame.xy = frame[c("x", "y")]
coordinates(frame.xy ) <- ~x+y
plot(frame.xy )

#Define the grid extent
x.range <- as.numeric(c(-4.445833,9.484722))  # min/max longitude of the interpolation area
y.range <- as.numeric(c(40.50306,51.2))  # min/max latitude of the interpolation area

#Create a data frame from all combinations of the supplied vectors or factors. See the description of the return value for precise details of the way this is done. Set spatial coordinates to create a Spatial object. Assign gridded structure:
grd <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = x.range[1], to = x.range[2], by = 0.1), 
                   y = seq(from = y.range[1], to = y.range[2], by = 0.1)) 
# expand points to grid
coordinates(grd) <- ~x + y
#to pixel
gridded(grd) <- TRUE
#Plot the weather station locations and interpolation grid:
plot(grd, cex = 1.5, col = "grey")

#les lon et lat
points(frame.xy, pch =1, col = "black", cex = 0.1)
#Interpolate surface and fix the output
idw <- idw(formula = temperature ~ 1, locations = frame.xy, 
           newdata = grd)  # apply idw model for the data

residual_grid = raster(idw, "var1.pred")
contourr <- rasterToContour(residual_grid)

library(leaflet)
## Initialisation 
m <- leaflet(padding = 0)
m <- addTiles(m)## Ajout des pays-
m <- addPolygons(map = m, data = FRA, opacity = 100, 
                 color = "#FAFCFA", 
                 weight = 0.25,popup = NULL,
                 options = list(clickable = FALSE), 
                 fill = T, fillColor = "#B3C4B3", 
                 fillOpacity = 100)
## Ajout des cercles
for ( i in 1:103) { 
  m <-addCircleMarkers(map = m, 
                       lng = dataJson[[i]]$longitude,
                       lat = dataJson[[i]]$latitude,
                       radius=5, weight = 0.25, 
                       stroke = T, opacity = 100,
                       fill = T, fillColor = "#920000", 
                       fillOpacity = 100,
                       popup = dataJson[[i]]$station,
                       color = "white")
}  
m <- fitBounds(map = m, 
               lng1 = -4.445833,
               lat1 = 40.50306,
               lng2 = 9.484722, 
               lat2 =  50.56417)
m<-addPolylines(map=m,data =contourr,fillOpacity=5,fillColor = "transparent",opacity=10,weight=1)
m<-addRectangles(map=m,
                 lng1=9.484722, lat1=40.50306,
                 lng2=-4.445833, lat2=51.2,
                 fillColor = "transparent"
)

## Dimensions de la carte
m$width <- 1000
m$height <-700

library(htmlwidgets)
saveWidget(m, 'contour.html', selfcontained = FALSE)
```

This is the result:

[image]

Now, I am looking a method for filling the contour levels with grain (texture).

EDIT:

I show you what I've done
I added a grid raster then I intersected with the card
[image]

but my ultimate goal is to combine texture with temperature value so the change in the value changes with grain like this :
[image]

I don't know how do it. please give me suggestion

Comment: as an alternative, you could produce a fillled contour map, save it as a raster and then added to your leaflet plot; see for yourself https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/raster.html

Comment: I was unable to find the raster "nc/oisst-sst.nc", Can you help me ?

Comment: nc/oisst-sst.nc is the raster used in that example. you already have a raster, have you tried        leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addRasterImage(residual_grid, colors = pal, opacity = 0.8)

Comment: I got the following error : Error in raster::projectRaster(x, raster::projectExtent(x, crs = sp::CRS(epsg3857))) : 
  input projection is NA

Comment: you just need to set your projection this http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/projection should help you to do it.

Comment: ok, it works thank you very much, I look for a method instead of the colors I would texture ,it's possible in R?

Comment: I don't know about texture, but filled.contour (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/filled.contour.html) will color the density plot

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is to display another layer on your map.

I would add a new layer just on top of the base layer which would be your residual_grid raster layer with a nice colour map on it. If it has a decent opacity assigned to it, you will still be able to see through it and the contours will be superimposed upon it.  I would also suggest labelling the contours(if they are polylines then perhaps the labels would render along them instead of inside them as polygons do).  I would also choose different display for your FRA polygons...perhaps just colour the boundaries of those. However, if you implement turning layers on and off, I would then put the FRA on top of the residual_grid raster.

Some example code and docs can be found here: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/raster.html
As they mention, if your raster resolution is big, then you will take a hit on bandwidth when a user is downloading the page.

Comment: +1,thank you for your opinion,
in fact I did all that, my current goal is to add texture, which grain variation  changes proportionally to the temperature value (based on contour levels)

Comment: @zina_GIS looking at your examples of texture, I think those would be very noisy. (lots of lines and criss-crosses, etc.)  Also, you would need discrete bins to assign the textures to...instead of a continuously changing colour.  https://github.com/teastman/Leaflet.pattern may help with leaflet polygon fill patterns.

Comment: yes it is true you are right; but this is just to show you my need to I use just a single layer to the entire map there was not a relationship with the value of temperature.