# Automatically filling contours by different type of hatching?

Tags: leaflet, r

I applied a question a few days ago here [Filling contour levels with grain (texture) using Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174750/filling-contour-levels-with-grain-texture-using-leaflet), I still found no answer I try to well exposed the problem here again in another way.

if we have a set of contour like this:
[image]

and if extracted from each contour with:

```
res <- lapply(slot(contourr, "lines"), function(x) lapply(slot(x, "Lines"),
                                                     function(y) slot(y, "coords")))
```

extract results:

```
    [[11]]
    [[11]][[1]]
               [,1]     [,2]
     [1,] -4.755523 48.01243
     [2,] -4.905347 48.21411
     [3,] -4.898013 48.44938
     [4,] -4.797207 48.68465
     [5,] -4.755523 48.71862
     [6,] -4.520381 48.87972
     [7,] -4.285239 48.90199
     [8,] -4.050097 48.88533
     [9,] -3.818382 48.68465
    [10,] -3.814954 48.58543
    [11,] -3.802051 48.44938
    [12,] -3.814954 48.42720
    [13,] -3.859241 48.21411
    [14,] -4.050097 47.97935
    [15,] -4.051804 47.97884
    [16,] -4.285239 47.85236
    [17,] -4.520381 47.81936
    [18,] -4.725150 47.97884
    [19,] -4.755523 48.01243

    [[11]][[2]]
                [,1]     [,2]
     [1,] -1.9338175 43.13232
     [2,] -1.9974500 43.27341
     [3,] -1.9952776 43.50868
     [4,] -1.9338175 43.64064
     [5,] -1.8453338 43.74395
     [6,] -1.6986754 43.85193
     [7,] -1.4635333 43.90846
     [8,] -1.2283911 43.89236
     [9,] -0.9932490 43.89244
    [10,] -0.8438516 43.74395
    [11,] -0.8192621 43.50868
    [12,] -0.9932490 43.33291
    [13,] -1.0656100 43.27341
    [14,] -1.2283911 43.07279
    [15,] -1.2625129 43.03814
    [16,] -1.4635333 42.93000
    [17,] -1.6986754 42.96119
    [18,] -1.8531391 43.03814
    [19,] -1.9338175 43.13232


    [[12]]
    [[12]][[1]]
               [,1]     [,2]
     [1,] -1.698675 43.18729
     [2,] -1.778287 43.27341
     [3,] -1.784724 43.50868
     [4,] -1.698675 43.60159
     [5,] -1.463533 43.69343
     [6,] -1.262507 43.50868
     [7,] -1.289913 43.27341
     [8,] -1.463533 43.09846
     [9,] -1.698675 43.18729


    [[13]]
    [[13]][[1]]
              [,1]     [,2]
    [1,] -1.463533 43.25529
    [2,] -1.499650 43.27341
    [3,] -1.542295 43.50868
    [4,] -1.463533 43.55070
    [5,] -1.417816 43.50868
    [6,] -1.445557 43.27341
    [7,] -1.463533 43.25529
```

is that possible filling the contour with a density (texture) so as to show an evolution ?

what I did, I manually extract a courbe and I PLOTE with a density like this:

code :

```
inter= read.table("/Users/insa/Documents/Biblio-graphique/test/inter.csv", header=TRUE)

plot(FRA)
a=polygon(inter,density=c(100,100),add=TRUE)
```

result :
[image: contour-texture]

so it can do for the rest of the contours with an automatic density change that shows an evolution,
I begin with R, can someone please oriente me just wondering if this track can solve my problem,

[Filling bars in barplot with textiles in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338103/filling-bars-in-barplot-with-textiles-in-ggplot2?lq=1)
I found this solution here:
but I can not get to apply my example

Comment: @Davdatta Tegshe :  excuse my English, I did interpolation and I created a raster (look at my old post : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174750/filling-contour-levels-with-grain-texture-using-leaflet), now I looking for rempalcer color by the texture (grain) in order to mount a variation of grain (when the value augmentre grain varies proportionally to the temperature value)

Comment: exactly what I want

Comment: From your first Image, it looks like you have Polygon data; If so there are multiple way of doing it; Without a webserver, you can do it in Leflet by using https://github.com/lnaweisu/leaflet-polygon-fillPattern

Comment: it means creating multiple image that carries different type of hatching?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33685/discussion-between-devdatta-tengshe-and-zina-gis).

Comment: ok , I'm there.

Comment: A good example of fill pattern instead of colors here : http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucfbpve/papers/VermeeschIGR2003/chinazones2.jpg ,